# @nrwl/react:stories does not generate Storybook stories

Tags: reactjs, storybook, monorepo, nrwl

I've a package called `component-library` which contains an `index.ts` file at the `src` folder:

```
/packages/component-library/src/index.ts
```

The contents of the `index.ts` are as follow:

```
export { default as Button } from './components/Button/Button';
```

And the contents of the file at `/packages/component-library/src/components/Button.tsx` are:

```
export function Button() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Button!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

I'm trying to generate a story using `@nrwl/react:stories`:

```
nx g @nrwl/react:stories --project=component-library
```

Which outputs:

```
>  NX  Generating @nrwl/react:stories

✔ Do you want to generate Cypress specs as well? (y/N) · false
```

But no story is generated, what I'm missing?

Comment: are you sure that you can use `false`? Have your tried `n` instead?

Comment: Yes, I press "N" and the terminal displays "false".

Comment: where you able to find a solution? I have the same problem..

Comment: Nope, no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the components folder to lib.

From `src/components/` to `src/lib/`

This is because the default value in `.storybook/main.js` resolves to `/src/lib`.